# How to center nav ul?

Tags: html, css

how to set my nav ul in mobile-mode to center?! 
Thx in advance

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4yf6/1/)

```
    nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 2% 5px;
    padding: 15px 0; 
    width: 50px;
    color: white;
    background: #e44d26;
}
```

Comment: the Fiddle you provided is really bad, and ppl dont give a damn when you dont give a damn. try to fix your fiddle next time you post something

Comment: this template: http://www.initializr.com/

Comment: i just try to edit mobile vision of this template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your result that works btw

http://jsfiddle.net/p4yf6/3/

```
nav {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav ul li, nav li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: no problem, try to make a better fiddle for the purpose next time, so you dont get as uch downvotes.